# pthread segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

Can somebody point out why my code is throwing segmentation fault? Most likely I am making a mistake when calling `pthread_create()` but I am failing to understand the mistake. Can somebody point out where am I going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int x = 0;
int counter =
    0;  // This is the global variable that all the threads will increment.
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void* addcounter(void* threadid) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  int* id = (int*)threadid + 1;
  int* y = (int*)x;
  int total = (*id) * (*y);
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    counter += 1;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int thread_count = 0;
  int loop_count = 0;
  int expected_value = -1;

  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("Usage: threads <no_of_threads> <no_of_loops>\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  thread_count = atoi(argv[1]);
  loop_count = atoi(argv[2]);
  x = loop_count;

  // Start your implementation after this comment.
  pthread_t* threads;
  threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * thread_count);
  int t;
  int flag = 0;
  for (t = 0; t < thread_count; t++) {
    int* z = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *z = t;
    flag = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, addcounter, (void*)z);
  }
  if (flag != 0) {
    printf("error in creating threads");
    exit(0);
  }

  for (t = 0; t < thread_count; t++) pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
  // Do not change the code below this comment
  return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

How should I resolve this error?

Comment: Yes, what is this `int* y = (int*) x;`? `x` is an integer and not a pointer.

Comment: Compile with -g, and run it  with gdb, it will tell you where is crashing

Comment: Ohh Bo Persson got it

Comment: @BoPersson what should I change?

Comment: "*`(int*)threadid + 1;`*" why the `+1`?

Answer (score 0):

first thing, you should initialize `mutex` variable with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.

```
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

or you can call `pthread_mutex_init(&lock,0)` from main thread to initialize `lock`.

second thing, replace below statement

```
 int* y = (int*) x;
```

with

```
 int* y = (int*) &x;
```

because `y` should have `valid address` else you can't perform `*y` later(as you are doing)

I hope it helps.

Comment: @ShahzaibRahim check now.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple pointer issues in

```
void* addcounter(void* threadid) { 
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  int* id = (int*)threadid + 1;    // <== A
  int* y = (int*)x;                // <== B
  int total = (*id) * (*y);        // <== C
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    counter += 1;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

Explanations

- A: probably `int id = *(int *)threadid + 1;`
- B: `int *y = (int *)x` will have `y` pointer set to `x`... an `int` dangerous! Was probably `int y = x;` (?)
- C: Then fix the total `int total = id + y;` (the following loop is not necessary, `counter += total;` is enough